# Oracle query by column1 where column2 is the same

Tags: oracle, join

I have a table like this in Oracle 9i DB:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | a    |
|    3 | a    |
|    4 | b    |
|    5 | b    |
+------+------+
```

Col1 is the primary key, Col2 is indexed.
I input col1 as condition for my query and I want to get col1 where col2 is the same as my input.
For example I query for 1 and the result should be 1,2,3.
I know I can use self join for this, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What is wrong with doing a self join?

Comment: I'm just being curious if I can avoid using the same table multiple times in a single query or if there is a faster way.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with joining a table to itself, and self join really seems like the best option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call this a semi-join: does it satisfy your 'no self joins' requirement?:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM YourTable
   WHERE Col2 IN ( SELECT t2.Col2
                     FROM YourTable t2
                    WHERE t2.Col1 = 1 );
```

I'd be inclined to avoid the `t2` range variable like this:

```
  WITH YourTableSearched
       AS ( SELECT Col2
              FROM YourTable
             WHERE Col1 = 1 )
    SELECT * 
      FROM YourTable
     WHERE Col2 IN ( SELECT Col2
                       FROM YourTableSearched );
```

but TNH I would probably do this:

```
  WITH YourTableSearched
       AS ( SELECT Col2
              FROM YourTable
             WHERE Col1 = 1 )
    SELECT *
      FROM YourTable
           NATURAL JOIN YourTableSearched;
```

Comment: While these are possible, I would prefer a simple self-join to any of them -- the best that you could hope for is that they would optimise to the same plan as a simple self-join. The DISTINCT in the last one seems redundant also.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Whether it's better (i.e. more performant) than using a self-join, particularly if there is an index on col1, col2, is anyone's guess.

Assuming col1 is unique, you could do:

```
SELECT col1
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               MAX(CASE WHEN col1 = :p_col1_value THEN col2 END) OVER () col2_comparison
        FROM   your_table)
WHERE col2 = col2_comparison;
```

And with :p_col1_value = 1:

```
      COL1
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

And with :p_col1_value = 5:

```
      COL1
----------
         4
         5
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot to state that Col1 is primary key and Col2 is indexed.

Comment: I wouldn't mind it if you'd add, "but this would clearly be an insane choice" to the answer :)